# Starting mjpg stream from a PHP file with shell_exec

Tags: php, video-streaming, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to start the mjpg process from inside a PHP file on my Raspberry Pi. This is the code I am using in the PHP file.

```
<?php
//this execution does not work, nor does it echo anything if i try and echo it
$cmd = 'mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -y -r 640x480 -f 10" -o "/usr/local/lib/output_http.so -p 8090 -w /var/www/mjpg_streamer"';
shell_exec($cmd);
?>

<img src = "http://ip:8090/?action=stream" />
```

The command works if I execute it directly from the shell and the stream also works in this case, but I want the process to start whenever I access the page, which is not happening right now.
What's the mistake?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions to debug that the PHP page suggests? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php. Seems like more people had problem with debug.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is *(almost certainly)* due to a permission based problem.

More than likely when you execute the `mjpg_streamer` library from the CLI you're logged in as someone with `sudoer` permissions or the like, who can easily execute this.

You must realize that the `user` who will be making the request to execute the `mjpg_streamer` library will be the same user that owns the instance of `Apache` handling the request.

In this scenario, the easiest way to troubleshoot this would be to log into the CLI and then `su www-data` (likely who owns your instance of apache) and check if you can then run it. If you get a `permission denied`, then you'll need to change how access to that library is granted. Changing ownership of the library is probably not the best bet, but you could likely get away with modifying the group.